# How to undo: sudo chown -R username:username on home

Tags: permissions, ownership

I accidentally ran the command:

> sudo chown -R username:username *

on home directory (username = mili). Now I often have problems with group permissions when working on projects.
Fix that work is to run:

> sudo chgrp -R www-data project-name/

on every project.
Is there way to fix this permanently other than reinstalling OS?

Comment: You already know how to fix it, so what is the problem?

Comment: It's necessary to do it every time, I'm looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: For example, I create a few projects weekly (Laravel mostly). There is logs and cache folders witch dynamically create files. Whenever that happens I have to run this command because newly created files couses group permission errors.

Comment: Do you have the `setgid` bit set on the root of your project directory by any chance? if so, files created in it were possibly inheriting `www-data` group ownership previously - but are now inheriting your primary group

Comment: I don't think so. Is this correct way to check, run "ls -ld", "ls -la" and look for 's'? If so, than no, there isn't seetgid bit.

Comment: This problem also occurs with ".git/objects" data, **insufficient permission**. With your suggestion in mind, I found a possible solution for this part. `git config --global core.sharedRepository group`. I don't think this will solve the original problem, but I'll test.

Comment: "Is there way to fix this permanently other than reinstalling OS?" we can only answer this for regular Ubuntu. From your answer it seems you use git and apache webserver in there That  should have been in your answer; nobody was going to take that into account.

Comment: Yes, you are right. At first, I had a lot of different problems with permissions and the only thing that happened is the one I mentioned in the question. Going through each problem separately in the next days led to a real problem. @Rinzwind At the moment question is bad, should I delete it, leave it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the most troubling consequences.

Apache access problem solution (new files wasn't owned by the same group):

> chgrp www-data ~/projects
>
> chmod g+s ~/projects

Insufficient permission for **.git/objects**:

> git config --global core.sharedRepository group

Comment: Sorry but you should not put files in you home under another name. Your home needs to be yours and some files need to be root. I would always put a website in its own directory with its own user and group

Comment: Why is that? As I see it, I'm still the owner, I just changed group so apache can handle it. Where do you put projects?  I found it easy to be under home directory so I can regularly backup literally everything to an external drive.

Comment: I/We tend to use /opt/. Our projects are done by more than 1 person and we have 2 people that admin /opt/ It is also on a separate instance so it can be attached to different cloud instances. the reason for my comment is exactly what you did: if you mess up permissions in /home/ and you need to fix it you make life more difficult to fix it if there are more than your user ;)